# How can i scan over a square matrices using php / for loop?

Tags: php, arrays, loops, matrix

I need to write some code using some for-loops which tests the values of some array data.

1st pass: checking the following...

```
{x0,y0}
```

2nd pass: checking the 4 bits of data...

```
{x0,y0}, {x1,y0}, 
{x0,y1}, {x1,y1}.
```

3rd pass: checking 9 bits of data...

```
{x0,y0}, {x1,y0}, {x2,y0}, 
{x0,y1}, {x1,y1}, {x2,y1},
{x0,y2}, {x1,y2}, {x2,y2}.
```

My little brain doesn't seem to want to function to get this answered. Can anyone help?

Comment: FYI: the matrices continues to get larger past the 3rd pass, it doesn't just stop there.

Comment: This does not look like PHP (I guess it's a rough image you want to give), can you tell anything about the underlying data-structure (how does that array looks like?) and what do you mean by scan?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

for ($pass = 0; $pass < count($matrix); $pass++)
{
    for ($i = 0; $i <= $pass; $i++)
    {
        for ($j = 0; $j <= $pass; $j++)
        {
            checkbit($matrix[$i][$j]);
        }
    }   
}

?>
```

Maybe something like this?

Answer (score 0):

You could start with a simple function that operates on the matrix:

```
function scan($x, $y) {...}
```

Additionally the canvas has a range for x and y, the starting number and it's ending number:

```
range x/y: 0,0/0,0
```

or later on:

```
range x/y: 0,2/0,2
```

If you say that the ranges always start at `0`, and both ranges always have the same upper value, this can be reduced as one variable: `$range`. You can then just iterate over the matrix easily ([Demo](http://codepad.org/ksqNMUqM)):

```
$range = 2;

foreach(range(0, $range) as $y)
    foreach(range(0, $range) as $x)
        scan($x, $y);

function scan($x, $y)
{
...
}
```

As `$range` depends on the number of the current pass, you can specify the maximum number of passes in `$passes` and iterate over it changing `$range` based on `$pass` ([Demo](http://codepad.org/Gsx9seGq)):

```
$passes = 3;

foreach(range(1, $passes) as $pass)
{
    $range = $pass-1;
    foreach(range(0, $range) as $y)
        foreach(range(0, $range) as $x)
            scan($x, $y);
}
```